# Regarding sql instr function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Oracle 10g is the db. 
The below query fails when extracting the date.

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE ( SUBSTR (file_name , INSTR (file_name , '_', -1, 2)+ 2, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')  from dual;
```

I noticed we receive the below two file name of different  naming formats.

> 660.ASSD.0063.20100923.0409.PTH2.IAC1.gcr_H201009231416151671_bbor.ddr
>   660.ASSD.M2K_20110309121547_489.ddr

For one file the above query works .  The other file 660.ASSD.M2K_20110309121547_489.ddr 
it extracts "01103091"  and does a to_date fails.  How can i modify this query so it works for both the file formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use REGEXP_REPLACE to strip-out letters from the file name.

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE ( SUBSTR (regexp_replace(file_name, '[A-Z][a-z]', '')
                           , INSTR (regexp_replace(file_name, '[A-Z][a-z]', '') , '_', -1, 2)+ 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  It didn't work if i have the regex as '[A-Z][a-z]'. So I changed it to '[A-Z]|[a-z]'

Answer (score 4):

Use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('660.ASSD.0063.20100923.0409.PTH2.IAC1.gcr_H201009231416151671_bbor.ddr', '\d{14,17}'), 0, 8), 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  from dual;
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('660.ASSD.M2K_20110309121547_489.ddr', '\d{14,17}'), 0, 8), 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. What does '\d{14,17}' looks for?

Comment: @Arav: it is: `\d` == a digit, `{14,17}` - 14 to 17 digits in a row